# adding background image to Outlet Collection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sdk

I have created an outlet collection for several buttons , now I need change the background of the buttons , here is my code but compiler gives me an error :

```
[outlet makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateSelected)];
```

Error :

> Expected ':'

how can I solve it ?

EDITED :

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"];
[outlet makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:)withObject:imgView];  
[imgView release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put arguments in `@selector(...)`. You need to use `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:`, e.g. your code should be *something* like

```
[EsOutlet makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:) withObject:img];
```

I say *something* like because I don't think there's a way to do this for a selector that takes more than one argument.

Comment: thank you,but application will be crashed ! would you please see my edited code ?

Comment: There is no `setBackgroundImage:` method for a `UIButton`, only `setBackgroundImage:forState:`. You're trying to call a method that doesn't exist. That's why I said _something like_ in my answer. So, you should probably take the advice of the other posters here and just iterate over the objects yourself. You could also add a `setBackgroundImage:` method to `UIButton` with a category, but that's more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have parameters inside `@selector` statement. Since there is no `makeObjectsPerformSelector` that would take two parameters in NSArray, you need to iterate through objects and call `setBackgroundImage:forState:` method on your own.

E.g.

```
for (UIButton *b in outlet) {
    [b setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your selector syntax is incorrect.  You can't supply paramaters to a `@selector` statement.

Since you need to supply multiple parameters (image + control state), you should iterate through `EsOutlet` and perform your actions:

```
for (UIControl *control in EsOutlet)
{
     //perform action on control
}
```